# 'Vulnerable' Without Negative Connotations

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

The word vulnerable has a negative connotation - as seemingly a weakness. I'd like suggestions for replacement word that has a positive (therefore, strength) connotation. 
Thank you

Comment: This is a bit like asking for a synonym for "sad" that doesn't sound so, y'know, unhappy.

Comment: Perhaps you could offer more context so that we can offer you a proper synonym? It's hard to think of any word that could mean 'vulnerable' without also meaning 'having a weakness'. Perhaps you are looking for a different word entirely, if 'vulnerable' is not suiting you.  In which case, try to describe the word you are looking for, rather than trying to make a 'synonym' for vulnerable.  After all, if it were a synonym, you could simply look up online any number of synonym lists and find an appropriate word.

Comment: It may not seem so at first blush, but "open" has much in common with "vulnerable," in the sense of not on guard or defended or walled/armored for protection.

Comment: @Sven Yargs I strongly suspect this is what the asker is looking for, but I don't want to put words in their mouth.  I would suggest to the asker that they edit their question to make this clear.

Comment: I think this would depend a lot on what's being described. Is this a person who's vulnerable to peer pressure? A strategically vulnerable chess position? An argument in a debate which is vulnerable to criticism? A military target that is vulnerable to attack?

Comment: Self confident? assertive?

Comment: Vulnerable in terms of humility is both a strength and a weakness. "The more vulnerable you are, the stronger you appear," is a principle in human relationships.

Answer (score 3):

For emotional vulnerability, you can use ***sensitive,*** which has more neutral connotations. You can use it in praise or criticism, although in the latter case it's common to make the criticism explicit rather than implied:

> I like him because he's sensitive.
>   He annoys me because he's too sensitive.

Also, note that *vulnerable* itself has less of a negative connotation when it comes to emotions than it does in a strategic context.

Answer (score 1):

Without a context, it's difficult.

*Open* to suggestions is a strength if they're benevolent, whereas it would be a weakness if the suggestions were evil.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you avoid some level of negative connotation.

'Susceptible' might be more neutral.

Comment: I think 'susceptible' is still a bit negative.